# iOS UITableView: What is difference between the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: and tableView(_:prefetchRowsAt:) methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Both these functions can be used for fetching paginated data as the user scrolls through the list. But are there any significant advantages of one over other? Which is better for implementing pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`willDisplayCell` is called *when the cell is about to be displayed* and is subject to the developer handling corner cases in terms of repeat displays, etc. It is intended to be used to perform cheap state-update operations on the cells in question -- not to prefetch data.

`prefetchRowsAt`, on the other hand, is called well ahead of time and allows you  'breathing room' to kick off potentially expensive operations that your cells depend on.

[The docs for `prefetchRowsAt` state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching/1771764-tableview):

> The table view calls this method on the main dispatch queue as the user scrolls, providing the index paths for cells ***it is likely to display in the near future***.
>
> Use your implementation of this method to start any expensive data loading operations. Always load your data asynchronously and forward the results to your table's data source object. Table views do not call this method for cells they require immediately, so your data source object must also be able to fetch the data itself.

Prefetch operations can also be cancelled by the `UITableView` when it calls the  [`tableView(_, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching/1771765-tableview) function on your data source.

So, yea, there's quite a difference. One option requires a whole lot more work than the other.

Answer (score 0):

from apple documentation i think that's the difference you are looking for.

**prefetchRowsAt:** Providing the index paths for cells it is likely to display in the near future. Use your implementation of this method to start any expensive data loading operations.

Vs

**willDisplayCell:**
send message just before it uses cell to draw a row,This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color